# How to detect a file change using Windows batch?

Tags: batch-file, comparison, file-monitoring

I want to monitor a specific file. Everytime it changes I want to get notified.
In Linux there is a perfect tiny program for that task called `monit`. Unfortunately I don't have such a tool in Windows :-(

I looked around for file monitor programs which are built-in in Windows - but could not find anything. There are a some tools to compare files like `fc` or `find` where you can "look" inside files. But they don't really help me.

Is there a possibility to monitor file changes using a batch file without installing extra software?

Comment: When a file is changed the Archive attribute is turned on.  So you could just monitor for that and have your monitoring script remove the Archive attribute after it detects the change.

Comment: There is also a wonderful application for watching a file change on Windows: __PowerShell__. It can be done also with a batch file processed by `cmd.exe` but not event driven as with PowerShell and much more complicated as the batch file must also find out if the modified file is already accessible again, i.e. when has the other application closed the file. As long as the file is opened by another application for read and/or write operations, it is most likely not possible to open the file by `cmd.exe` for processing its contents as exclusive shared file access is the default on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**This solutions works with a temporary copy of the monitored file.** Thus you can even monitor a file which is on a **write-protected network drive** (where you can't reset an archive attribute).

The following batch file compares the time stamp of a file with a copy of that file.
If there is a difference it opens `notepad.exe` and shows both versions.

Usage:
`DetectFileChange.bat C:\FileToMonitor.txt C:\Temp\CopyOfMonitoredFile.txt`

`DetectFileChange.bat`

```
@echo off
REM DetectFileChange.bat
REM Michael Hutter / Februar 2024

if "%1"=="" goto Syntax
if "%2"=="" goto Syntax
if not exist "%1" goto Syntax

set "originalFile=%1"
set "copyFile=%2"

rem Überprüfen, ob die Kopie existiert
if not exist "%copyFile%" (
    echo Kopie der Datei existiert nicht. Erstelle eine neue Kopie...
    copy "%originalFile%" "%copyFile%"
)

:Restart
rem Auslesen der Zeitstempel
for %%A in ("%originalFile%") do set "originalTimeStamp=%%~tA"
for %%B in ("%copyFile%") do set "copyTimeStamp=%%~tB"

rem Vergleichen der Zeitstempel
if "%originalTimeStamp%" neq "%copyTimeStamp%" (
    echo Die Datei wurde geändert!
    call :TheFileWasChanged %originalFile% %copyFile% "%originalTimeStamp%" "%copyTimeStamp%" TempAlertFile
    copy /Y "%originalFile%" "%copyFile%"
    del %TempAlertFile%
) else (
    echo Die Datei wurde nicht geändert. %originalTimeStamp% gleich %copyTimeStamp%
)
REM Uncomment the following two lines if you want to run this file in a loop
REM timeout /t 30 > nul
REM goto Restart
echo Ende
exit /b

:Syntax
echo Detect file changes (by file timestamp)
echo Syntax:
echo   %0 ^<FileToMonitor^> ^<CopyOfMonitoredFile^>
echo   %0 C:\FileToMonitor.txt C:\Temp\CopyOfMonitoredFile.txt
exit /b

:TheFileWasChanged
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set sChangeAlertFile=C:\Temp\ChangeAlert.txt
set sFileNameNow=%1
set sFileNameBefore=%2
set sTimestampNow=%3
set sTimestampBefore=%4
echo The file !sFileNameNow! has changed: (!sTimestampBefore! to !sTimestampNow!) > !sChangeAlertFile!
echo. >> !sChangeAlertFile!
echo New Content: >> !sChangeAlertFile!
echo ============ >> !sChangeAlertFile!
type !sFileNameNow! >> !sChangeAlertFile!
for %%a in (1 2) do echo. >> !sChangeAlertFile!
echo Old Content: >> !sChangeAlertFile!
echo ============ >> !sChangeAlertFile!
type !sFileNameBefore! >> !sChangeAlertFile!
start notepad !sChangeAlertFile!
timeout /t 2 > nul
(endlocal & set %5=%sChangeAlertFile%)
goto :eof
```

You could either run the program (e. g. every hour) by the Windows Task Scheduler to perform a check.
The other possibility is to uncomment the following two lines:

```
REM timeout /t 30 > nul
REM goto Restart
```

Then the script will do a check every 30 seconds without being closed.

### And that's what it looks like when a change is detected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal, but the closest you'll get without having to install 3rd party programs.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "lastT="
:mon
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell (Get-Item "%~1"^).LastWriteTime') do (
    if not defined lastT set "lastT=%%a"
    if not "%%a" == "!lastT!" (
          echo "%~1" was modified at %%a
          set "lastT=%%a"
   )
)
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
goto mon
```

Just run the file as `monitor.cmd "C:\path\to\file.txt"` (assuming you named the script `monitor.cmd`)

Example result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Squashman's comment:

a) remove the archive attribute from a file:

```
attrib -a file.txt
```

b) Windows sets this attribute whenever it creates a file or writes to it (this attribute is meant to be used to determine which files to backup for an incremental backup)

c) check if the file was changed (list the file if it has the archive attribute removed; discard errors and output - we don't need them here):

```
dir /a-a file.txt >nul 2>&1 && echo The file has changed.
```

d) goto a)

(instead of just echoing a message, you can of course `goto :payload`)

If you don't need to know *when* the file has been changed, just *that* it has been changed, this is the easiest way.